# CSS - Stacked DIV layout

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm looking for a compatible CSS layout that will support the following;

```
+-----+--------+
| A   | C      |
+-----+        |
| B   |        |
|     |        |
|     |        |
+-----+--------+
```

C is the container for the whole thing. A is a div that can vary in height, according to it's content (i.e. it's not a fixed height). B is a div that is displayed directly beneath A, and fills the remaining height from C, once A has taken it's share.

I'm hoping for a non-Javascript, non-table solution, hopefully!

**EDIT**: I should also add, that 'C' represents a container with a set height. In my current page, it is 100% of the height of the browser window.

Comment: what do you want to achive - why is the B has to stretch to the end ?
if it doesnt just set float left on A and width on A and C, 
the other option is to use CSS 'frameworks' like skeleton, twitter bootstrap or blueprint - make life easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with `display:table` property like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class='wrapper'>
   <div class='left'>
       <div class="table">
       <div class='a'>a</div>
             <div class='b'>b</div>
       </div>

   </div>
   <div class='c'>c</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
}
.wrapper > div{
    display:table-cell;
    width:50%;
}
.table > div{
    display:table-row;
}
.left{background:yellow}
.a{
    background:red;
}
.b{
    background:green;
}
.c{
    background:blue;
}
.table{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/X5Ze4/

Comment: This works quite well, except that a and b are the same height - I wanted a to be as small as it needs to be, and b to fill the rest. I managed to solve this by adding height: 0; to the a class. See: http://jsfiddle.net/Ywtwv/   Not pretty, but it works

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<div id='wrapper'>
   <div id='sidebar'>
             <div class='a'></div>
             <div class='b'></div>
   </div>
   <div id='main-content'>

   </div>
</div>
```

Then apply style according to your need.

Eg.

```
div#wrapper
{
  min-height:500px;
}
```

Comment: I should've said - C is a set height. Specifically it is the full height of the browser pane.

Answer (score 1):

i think you are looking like this:-

**HTML**

```
    <div id="c">ccccccccc
<div class="a">asfdaaaaaaaaas</div>
<div class="b">adffffffssssssssssssssssssssss</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    #c {
background:red;
}
.a {
background:blue;
width:200px;
float:left;
clear:both;
}
.b {
background:yellow;
width:200px;
```

}

see the live demo:- http://jsfiddle.net/PAJzK/16/

Comment: Not quite - see here once I've fixed the container height: http://jsfiddle.net/3cr3x/

Comment: use min-height or height:auto; rather than fixed height :-http://jsfiddle.net/3cr3x/2/

Answer (score 0):

I've had a go and come up with this, be careful though Content B is set to overflow hidden so when putting anything in there you'll have to consider whats in Content A.

**HTML**

```
<div id='wrapper'>
<div id='sidebar'>
         <div class='a'>Content A</div>
Content B
</div>
<div id='main-content'>
Main Content
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body{
margin:0;
padding:0
}
#wrapper{
float:left;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:green;
}
#sidebar{
float:left;
position:absolute;
width:30%;
height:100%;
background-color:red;
overflow:hidden;
}
.a{
float:left;
position:reative;
width:100%;
background-color:orange;
min-height:33%;
}
#main-content{
float:left;
position:absolute;
width:70%;
min-height:100%;
left:30%;
background-color:yellow;
}
```

The CSS could probably do with condensing but that's how I'd go about it.

[Edit: I'd use Sandeep's solution]

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AnBWP/